# Можно ли организовать подобие полиморфизма в css?

Tags: css

Подключаю к странице 2 css-файла, в котором прописаны классы с одинаковыми именами. Можно ли как-нибудь указать, чтобы страница оформлялась стилями из определенного файла? Как вообще браузеры обрабатывают ситуацию, когда в нескольких файлах прописан один и тот же класс, чье оформление берется?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Берется оформление второго класса, с учетом первого. То есть сначала применяется первое описание, потом перекрывающиеся позиции классов перезатираются вторым.

Если стоит !impotant, перезатирание не происходит. Если два импортанта, то обрабатываются как написано выше.

Чтобы страница оформлялась стилями определенного файла, можно использовать директиву

```
@media
```

Если нужно менять произвольно, лучше это делать просто отключая ненужные файлы яваскриптом.